# I have installed cuda 11.8 and cudnn 8.9.6, python 3.10, what pytorch versions i need to install to use the gpu

Tags: python, pycharm, gpu

pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118
was using this command to download the pytorch but pytorch is not connecting with gpu.

I am already working in a virtual environment, pytorch is connecting to gpu.

> NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA
> Corporation Built on Wed_Sep_21_10:41:10_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2022
> Cuda compilation tools, release 11.8, V11.8.89 Build
> cuda_11.8.r11.8/compiler.31833905_0 this is the nvcc --version